# Subplot not plotting correctly, while regular plot is - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a data set called curvefit and the following code `plot(curvefit,'b-')`

When this code is plotted I get this plot image

http://tinypic.com/r/fu7yo3/8

However when I try to do a subplot with `subplot(2,1,1); plot(curvefit,'b-')` I get this (actual subplot code to produce image uses `subplot(1,1,1)` to create larger image, result is the same)

http://tinypic.com/r/6dsgth/8

I've cleared my workspace of any extraneous variables, used clf beforehand. `Hold on` is not on, these plots are plotted seperately. I'm not sure what's going on or how to fix this. Thanks to anybody who can! Here is my code if it helps

```
 figure
 set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));
 span=61; 
 smooth349=smooth(updisplacementP349,span);
 subplot(2,1,1); plot(upliftdatesP349,smooth349,'b-')
 datetick('x')

 curvefit349=fit(upliftdatesP349',smooth349,'sin4');
 subplot(2,1,2); plot(curvefit349,'b-');
```

upliftdatesP349 is a 1 by 3038 row of dates with each date taken per day

updisplacementP349 is a 3038 by 1 vector of data. I'm new to stack overflow so I am not sure what the procedure is on posting exact code because mine pulls data from large text files which I can't post.

Comment: What are the dimensions for `curvefit`?  Is it a matrix with two columns?  I've never tried to plot matrices before and would do something like `plot(curvefit(:,1),curvefit(:,2),'b-')` instead.  When I tried the matrix form (first column x, and second column sin(x)) I did get a weird plot showing the sine wave and a diagonal line (much like yours).  Check the [plot with matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) link for info on plotting in this manner.  You may want to just stick with the plotting of the individual columns.

Comment: Please, post the full code, so that we can exactly recreate your case

Comment: curvefit is a 1x1 cfit value outputted by the `fit` command. The default way of plotting a cfit value as given by MATLAB documentation here http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/curve-fitting.html is the way I described in my original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's not exactly what you are after but you can turn off the other curve.

```
load hahn1
f = fit( temp, thermex, 'rat23' )
subplot(2,1,1);
h= plot(f,1:size(thermex),thermex);
set(h(1),'Visible','off');
subplot(2,1,2);
h= plot(f,1:size(thermex),thermex);
set(h(2),'Visible','off');
```

As for your example try this:

```
subplot(2,1,1);
h= plot(curvefit349,1:size(upliftdatesP349),upliftdatesP349);
set(h(1),'Visible','off');
subplot(2,1,2);
h= plot(curvefit349,1:size(upliftdatesP349),upliftdatesP349);
set(h(2),'Visible','off');
```

I think your problem could possibly be a bug in Matlab but the workaround above should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found a work around that is similar to yours. I've never encountered an actual "bug" in MATLAB before so I wasn't sure what to expect. There must be a way to get it to work the way it is. Until then though. Thanks!